# Move pagination numbers above plug-ins

Tags: pagination

I'm having the following problem:

[image]

I want to move the generated page numbers from `<!--nextpage-->` to appear below the post body, above the plugins (WordPress Related Posts, WP Author Box Lite & JetPack Share).

Looking at `single.php`, `wp_link_pages()` comes right after `the_content()`. Are these plug-ins adding their content to `the_content()`? The [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) seems to give some alternative usage. Is this the only solution or is there a plug-in that will help with this problem?

I'm using the BoldR Lite theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the content earlier than these plugins and add the navigation there.

Remove `wp_link_pages()` from the template, and add the following code to the theme:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ) {
    return $content . wp_link_pages( array( 'echo' => FALSE ) );
}, -1 ); // Lower number = higher priority.
```

Comment: I know this answer is old, but I have a question. I'm using WP 5.4.2, when I replaced wp_link_pages() with the above code, my pagination doesn't appear at all.

I'm using twenty seventeen theme, can you explain how does this code work?

Comment: @DarrylRN Should still work. If it doesn't – you need some in-depth debugging.

Comment: I put it exactly same in `post/content.php` and `page/content-page.php`, both give different bug results, in `post/content.php` the pagination doesn't show at all. in `page/content-page.php` the pagination repeatedly rendered and sometimes the snippet content is not being rendered. Do you have any working example?

Comment: @DarrylRN This code belongs to your theme's `functions.php`.