# How to remove wp_link_pages() from template

Tags: templates, pagination

The code in the answer of [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158974/move-pagination-numbers-above-plug-ins) works fine, but one part I don't understand:

> Remove `wp_link_pages()` from the template

Where is the exact code to remove? I looked into `/wp-includes/post-template.php`, but removing it there produces an error. At the moment, with using the code:

`add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ) {
    return $content . wp_link_pages( array( 'echo' => FALSE ) );
}, -1 ); // Lower number = higher priority.`

the pagination appears twice: One above and one below related posts. So I'll have to delete the second one, right? How does it work?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/184396/26350) approach can help, where you don't have to remove it from your template file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't remove it from `/wp-includes/post-template.php`. This is a WordPress core file and you should never edit any WordPress core file.

The [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/158975/110572) is talking about removing the call of `wp_link_pages` function within a [template file](https://codex.wordpress.org/Templates).

Which template file to edit depends on the theme and the URL you are visiting. Typically it should be `/wp-content/themes/<your-active-theme>/single.php`.

But templates can be divided in multiple files and call to `wp_link_pages` function may be in any of those template part files.

For example, in `twentyseventeen` theme, it can be found on multiple files. For `pages`, it's in:

```
/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/template-parts/page/content-page.php:
```

For posts, it's in:

```
/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/template-parts/post/content-audio.php
/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/template-parts/post/content-gallery.php
/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/template-parts/post/content-image.php
/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/template-parts/post/content-video.php
/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/template-parts/post/content.php
```

If you still cannot find which template file to edit for your currently active theme, you may [read this guide](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-find-which-files-to-edit-in-wordpress-theme/) to find out.

Read more about WordPress theme template files for [posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/post-template-files/) and [pages](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-templates/).

Also, while you remove the `wp_link_pages` function call from any template file, make sure you have basic understanding of PHP function calls. Since the function call may involve multiple lines.

## Update: How to remove `wp_link_pages` pagination from a Genesis Theme:

(Since it's mentioned in the comment that it's the Genesis `LifeStyle Pro` Theme)

Themes with `Genesis` framework handle pagination differently. With a Genesis Theme, you'll not actually find an explicit call to the `wp_link_pages` pagination function in the template files, as it's handled by the Genesis framework.

So in that case, ***remove the the CODE you used*** in the question, and instead, **use the following CODE**:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ) {
    remove_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'genesis_do_post_content_nav', 12 );
    return $content . wp_link_pages( array( 'echo' => FALSE ) );
}, -1 );
```

Now you'll not have the default pagination provided by your Genesis theme.

Comment: thank you for your detailled answer. I installed "What the file" and found 'single.php' as template. But there is no `wp_link_pages` inside. In all other templates of my "LifeStyle Pro" - Genesis-theme I couldn't find the item. Are you familiar with Genesis? Or anybody else?

Comment: Yes I shoud've, sorry. Where have I to add this line? In my custom-template-files? I have 5 custom-category-templates for my posts.

Comment: It is still doubled. I created the single.php in lifestyle pro and purged / flushed all caches on each level. But no effect so far.

Comment: @RainerBrumshagen I was able to reproduce your problem and found a better solution. Please use the new CODE in the **Update** section of the answer.

Comment: Yessss! Perfect! Exactly how I want to have this. Thank you very much!